# After creating a bootable Ubuntu USB, can I delete the ISO image from my download folder?

Tags: iso

After creating a bootable Ubuntu USB, can I delete the ISO image from my download folder? Its taking up precious space on my 160GB SSD Hard disk and I dont want to let that space go.

Comment: yes, you can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, it doesn't have anything to do with the USB anymore.

However...
First try booting your system using your bootable USB, if it worked and there was no problem then remove the ISO so in case of any problem you don't have to re-download the ISO.